# How to remove a word that matches at the beginning of each line

Tags: parsing, unix, text

I would like to ask, how could I remove lines contaning the pattern `AAA` at their beginning?

example:

**contents of file.txt:**

```
AAA/bb/cc/d/d/d/d/e
AAA/dd/r/t/e/q/e/tg
AAA/uu/y/t/r/e/w/q
123 234 456 AAA/f/f/f/f/g/g
555 999 000 AAA/y/g/h/u/j/k
```

I would like to remove the first three lines with this type of pattern but would like to keep the last two lines.

The output of the command should be:

```
123 234 456 AAA/f/f/f/f/g/g
555 999 000 AAA/y/g/h/u/j/k
```

How could I do it with a unix command?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed `/^AAA/d` file.txt
```

The `/^AAA/` is a regular expression which matches `AAA` at the beginning of a line (`^`). `d` deletes the selected lines.

[`man sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) for more information on the `sed` stream editor.